# insertar datos ajax laravel

Tags: laravel, ajax

Hola tengo el siguente codigo:

```
$('#newsletterbutton').on('click',function(){
       event.preventDefault();
       var email = $('#emailnews').val();
       $.ajax({
                   type:"ajax",
                   url: '/newsletter',
                   type: 'POST',
                   data: {email: email},
                   dataType: 'json',
                   success: function(){
                        alert('bien');
                   },
                   error: function(){
                       alert('mal');
                   },
               })
           }
      })
```

Mi controllador:

```php
function newsletter(Request $request)
    {
        $insert = DB::table('newsletter')
              ->insert(['email' => $request->email]);
        return response()->json ($insert);        
    }
```

y mi ruta:

```php
Route::post('/newsletter', 'MainController@newsletter');
```

mi problema que es siempre esta entrado en error no estaria entendiendo que estaria haciendo mal.
en mi head esta definido el crsf token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En laravel, se tiene un `token`, para evitar ataques **csrf** y que siempre son requeridos al momento de hacer una petición `post`.

Puedes agregarlo en una etiqueta `meta` o simplemente en un `input hidden`.

Ej:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{csrf_token()}}" name="_token" id="token">
```

O podrias añadirlo con `{{ csrf_field() }}`, que tan solo es su equivalente, lo que faltaria es enviarlo en tu ajax:

```
   var email = $('#emailnews').val();
   var _token = $('#token').val();
   $.ajax({
               type:"ajax",
               url: '/newsletter',
               type: 'POST',
               data: {email: email,_token:_token},
               dataType: 'json',
               success: function(){
                    alert('bien');
               },
               error: function(){
                   alert('mal');
               },
           })
       }
  })
```

Con eso tu problema debería de solucionarse.